# NPM installing nearly 202M of modules - this can't be right

Tags: reactjs, npm

So I am looking at my package.json file - and nothing looks particularly crazy:

```
{  
  "name": "application_name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-toggle": "^2.2.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.4.6",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-bootstrap-toggle": "^2.3.1",
    "react-cookie": "^3.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-load-script": "0.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && robocopy .\\build ..\\www /MIR",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

I've tried npm install, npm install --production and npm install --express

No matter what npm command I write, I get the following:

```
added 1425 packages from 862 contributors and audited 14585 packages in 15.876s
```

It ultimately is 202M - this can't be right, that's a HUGE number of modules

This is for a React project I am working on.

I only made this question because none of the other answers seemed to work for my situation.

Is there a solution to this problem? I am intending on compiling this into a mobile app and 202M is a huge footprint for what is a pretty simple app.

Comment: *I am intending on compiling this into a mobile app* - did you actually try to compile it to be worried about? These are development dependencies, react-scripts in particular.

Comment: This is my first react app, and I just installed various dependencies using npm install XXX - should I be doing something different?

Comment: I don't think I'm actually using react-scripts anywhere, I was considering it for use and decided against it.

Comment: To your "this can't be right..." comment, I leave you with this: [www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/6s0wov/heaviest_objects_in_the_universe](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/6s0wov/heaviest_objects_in_the_universe/)

Comment: You're using it right below, `"start": "react-scripts start"`. It's provided by CRA you've used to create the project. If it's your first project, you can be sure this is normal and there's no reason to worry about output size (yet).

Comment: Estus is right, it may seem big, but just because the node modules directory is so large that doesn't mean your users will have to download that much

Comment: My mine issue is - I am trying to produce an alpha here and submit it to Apple for alpha testers to test it - so while I am fine with having this huge library on my local - I don't want it in my created product - how do I export a version for compiling in Cordova?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

202Mb is almost completely occupied with development dependencies, `react-scripts`.

`react-scripts` is a bundle consisting Webpack and other tools that are necessary to run the project. It is provided by Create React App, which is just an executable that creates boilerplate project with `react-scripts`:

> This package includes scripts and configuration used by Create React
>   App.

`node_modules` size is adequate for complex configuration that CRA sets up. It doesn't affect the size of compiled application.

Comment: So will removing react-scripts from my package.json fix the problem? Like, how do I prepare a react app (alongside cordova - I decided this would be a faster approach than React Native for multi-platform). I want to launch on the iOS simulator right now and check how it works - but the build was taking a TON of time, which I assume is due to my node_modules size.

Comment: No, it won't fix the problem. There's no problem. You won't be able to build the project without  react-scripts. You would need to install and configure tools yourself otherwise. This is what CRA does for you. Tools occupy a lot of space and don't affect the size of compiled application. create-react-app default setup (the one that uses react-scripts) is intended for web apps. I cannot guarantee that it's perfectly suited for native mobile app. I'd expect that it's not.

Comment: You possibly need another setup, you can refer to https://github.com/johnkmzhou/cordova-create-react-app . This is a bit out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Hrm, this is sorta my problem though - when I run cordova emulate ios, it is very slow creating the simulated app - I am supposing this is due to my high number of NPM modules (I have my development directory symlinked into the ios directory) - if that question is a bit too derivative, I can always accept this answer and create another question I suppose

Comment: Yes, you can ask another question with your specific project. But it's possible that it works as intended. Webpack builds can be painfully slow. if you didn't do this before, you may have nothing to compare with.